# Deploy to root in wildfly in docker

Tags: java, docker, wildfly

Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
COPY target/TimeTable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  wildfly:
    image: jboss/wildfly
    container_name: wildfly
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "9990:9990"
  timetable:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - wildfly
```

webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-config.xml

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="8.0">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

If I deploy by my own hands to wildfly on host machine, everything runs as expected and on root page I see my `index.xhtml`. But when I deploy it to docker, `localhost:8080/` shows default wildfly welcome page. In logs in docker I see `Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'`, but still nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

The file name is `jboss-web.xml`.  I have different namespaces as you but I believe it's just the file name.  I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```